# TNS: listener error

Tags: java, exception

I need an urgent solution regarding TNS: listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack. When I am connecting Oracle database with jdbc connection (type 4), it is working well i.e. fetching data from oracle database, but after sometime an Exception is occurring telling that : TNS: listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack. This type of exception is occurring every time just after fetching more records from oracle. Please anybody suggest me any solution regarding my problem. I have written type 4 connection in servlet and connecting to oracle database.

Comment: ya i googled a lot but did not find any solution to this problem, please help me

Comment: no oracle 10g EE, I am connecting through type 4 jdbc connection to oracle 10g EE, after fetching records for sometimes, there is occurring an exception every time like that tns: listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing code, but a big fat guess would be that you are not correctly closing all of your connections, and as a consequence are using up all the sessions/processes on the server.

Comment: i can email you two files where i have written these codes, can i have your email id? i need urgent help

Comment: Probably best to put code on paste bin and post links here, you might get more people to look at them.

Answer (score 0):

Just like msandiford said above, please first check the obvious. I thought I had all of my plethora of connections closed but was missing one, which eventually, during processing, maxed out and threw the error.

Check and re-check all your connections and that you have also properly closed them. In my specific situation, I watched the sessions on the database as I stepped through code...suddenly I went from 9 to 88 and knew I'd found the issue.